# ActiveModel without rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

Is possible use ActiveModel without rails?. 
Is possible use ActiveModel in desktop application?

Answer (score 5):

With Rails 3 you can! Check out [this post on Rubyinside.com](http://www.rubyinside.com/rails-3-0s-activemodel-how-to-give-ruby-classes-some-activerecord-magic-2937.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example using the validations:

```
require 'active_model'

class Cat
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :id, :name

  validates_presence_of :name
  puts "meow!"

end
```

Testing out the class above:

```
$ irb -r ./cat.rb
meow!
irb(main):002:0> cat = Cat.new
=> #<Cat:0xb99e44>
irb(main):003:0> cat.valid?
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
=> false
irb(main):004:0> cat.name = "puss"
=> "puss"
irb(main):005:0> cat.valid?
=> true
```